# Protect the Sheet for manual entry but to allow entry, Edit, Delete via userform

Tags: excel, vba, password-protection

I Have created a data entry form in excel using VBA , I want to protect te database sheet to have manual entry but to allow save the data , edit the data and delete the data or row via vba userform.
I have coded the below written to protect the sheet.

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
Worksheets("Database").Protect Password:=True, UserinterfaceOnly:=True
End Sub
```

It is working fine but after some time it is giving me run time error 1004.
Along with this it is not allowing me to delete the previous data using delete button

Answer (score 0):

When you edit sheet even through with a VBA userform, sheet needs to temporarily unprotected. You can do it like this:

```
' Unprotect
Sheets("SHEET").Unprotect password:="PASSWORD"
'
'your code here
'
' Protect
Sheets("SHEET").protect password:="PASSWORD"
```

Answer (score 0):

### Delete Rows on Protected Worksheet

- If you are prepared to unlock entire rows, then you could prepare the worksheet with something like the following code.
- It is **not** to be used in the `Workbook_Open` event code; it is just some code to prepare the worksheet.
- Note `AllowDeletingRows:=True`.
- But, you cannot delete a row if all of the cells are not unlocked.
- The issue with rows (similarly with columns) is that if you delete one, the next row 'lands in the spot' of the deleted one. So e.g. if after using the example code the user deletes any of the allowed rows, than he wouldn't be able to delete row 50 which might just be the behavior that you require.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

' Remove this Sub when done.
Sub Allowed()
    
    Const AllowedRows As String = "2:50"
    Const pWord As String = "123"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database")
    
    With ws
        .Unprotect pWord
        .Cells.Locked = True ' Lock all cells.
        .EnableSelection = xlNoRestrictions
        .Rows(AllowedRows).Locked = False ' Unlock allowd rows.
        .Protect Password:=pWord, DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, _
          Scenarios:=True, AllowDeletingRows:=True
    End With

End Sub
```